# How to handle errors in hash tables in python 3?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, search, hashtable, indexoutofrangeexception

Getting a basic error in Hash tables

```
n = int(input("Enter the length of the array "))

a = [0 for i in range(n)]


for i in range(0,n):
    a[i] = int(input("Enter elements of array: "))

# maxi = max(a)
# print(maxi)

has = [[0 for i in range(n)] 
            for j in range(2)]

for i in range(0,n):
    if(a[i]>=0):
        has[a[i]][0] = 1
    else:
        has[abs(a[i])][1] = 1

search = int(input("Enter the element to be searched: "))

# if(search>0):


def search1(search):
    if(search>0):
        if(a[search][0] == 1):
            print("Present")
        else:
            print("Absent")

    else:
        search = abs(search)
        if(a[search][1] == 1):
            print("Present")
        else:
            print("absent")
```

Can anyone please help me out if why is this happening?
Error: **list index out of range**

This code first takes an array of input from the user and the numbers are then stored in a hash table based on positive or negative numbers. Then the search algorithm is made based on index itself to give the time complexity of O(1). But in between, I am getting a list index out of range error. Please help to solve the following error.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are simulating a hash using a list, right? Here is the problem: The expression

```py
[[0 for i in range(n)] 
            for j in range(2)]
```

generates a list of lists. If your print it, you'll see that is has two items (two lists), so an indexing operation like `a[i]` with i > 1 won't work. Maybe you wanted to generate a list with a different structure?

```py
[[0 for i in range(2)] 
            for j in range(n)]
```

Or you can change the indexing logic, e.g. `has[1][abs(a[i])] = 1`.

In general, it helps to print the state of the variables in between to stay informed about what's going on.